# Server client communication using Socket C#

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, ascii

I have created an application, which is communicating a server using IP/port. It is sending a ISO request string(Bitmaps in ASCII format) and receiving a response string same format. While Sending the bytes through socket.send and receiving the bytes in socket.receive method. I can see extended ASCII characters are getting changed on other side (Server side/Clint side). I am using below code. Can anyone suggest please, How to resolve the issue.

```
IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse("10.03.0.18");               

IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 12345);            

// Creation TCP/IP Socket using  
// Socket Class Costructor 
Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);             

sender.Connect(localEndPoint);
string requeststring = AccountValidationRequest();              

byte[] messageSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requeststring);

int byteSent = sender.Send(messageSent);

byte[] ServerResponse = new byte[1024];
int byteRecv = sender.Receive(ServerResponse); 
string ISO8583Message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ServerResponse, 0, byteRecv);

Console.WriteLine("Response received from server: --> :{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ServerResponse, 0, byteRecv));
```

Comment: getting changed to what, exactly? Show some examples of the text before and after, please.

Comment: Also, where is the code for the server side, please? Maybe it changes it on purpose? Are you expecting to get the data back completely unchanged?

Comment: Don't assume you are getting a message in one chunk.  Terminate each ascii message with a '\n' and after receiving make sure you are getting the '\n' before processing.

Comment: Server is sending me some binary string masking in ASCII format , when I am decoding that ASCII here in my application I am getting different Binary string. Example  Server sent:(Original Binary) sent in ascii format 11110000001100001000000000000001000011101000000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111110                   After Decoding I am getting : 00111111001100000011111100000001000011100011111100111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111110

Comment: This we are getting now : The bit map I am sending is 

11110000001100001000000100000001000010000010000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000110100

Server is getting it in after decoding

00111111001100000011111100000001000010000010000000111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000110100

Do you see any solution of it?

Answer (score 1):

As it was suggested in comments you should assert that you read all data, not only the first chunk.

```
Byte[] bytesReceived = new Byte[256];
int bytes = 0;

var ISO8583Message = "Response: \n";
do {
    bytes = sender.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
    ISO8583Message = ISO8583Message + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
}
while (bytes > 0);
```

There are some nice examples with using sockets on https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netframework-4.8.

Comment: I am getting response at a time in bulk(388 bytes). The server I am communicating with, Has a running application. So they will not change their code. I can only modify my part.